# UML relationship between object and class that creates list, but adds objects in method

Tags: java, uml

Something like this:

```
public class create {

  private List<Object> l  = new ArrayList<>();

  public void put() {

        Object o1 = new Object();

        l.add(o1);
    }
}
```

Unaccounting for the list, I'm assuming it's a dependency.
But what would the relationship between this class and Object be now?

Comment: Object is the superclass of all, to have a dependency to it is absolutely useless. With *List* you have much more than a dependency because *l* is an attribute typed *List*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship in this case would be an aggregation because of the `List<Object> l` attribute. The `create` class is an aggregate of class `Object`.

The definition of 'Aggregate' is:

> a whole formed by combining several (typically disparate) elements.

In UML specifically, an Aggregation relationship is defined as

> an association that represents a part-whole or part-of relationship
> or a
> "has a" association relationship

---

If `create` class did not have the `l` attribute, then it would be a dependency.

```
public class create {

  public void put() {

        List<Object> l  = new ArrayList<>();

        Object o1 = new Object();

        l.add(o1);
    }
}
```

This is because `create` class depends on `Object` class for its implementation of the `put()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between create and Object is an aggregation:

[image]

The multiplicity on the top is `*` because an Object can be part of zero or more create instances.

The multiplicity on the bottom is also `*` because an instance of the create class can have a list of zero or more Objects.

This class diagram hides the concrete implementation of the aggregation relationship. It is also possible to draw a more technical diagram which includes class ArrayList, but this is not what you ask.